# Совмещение 2 контекстов в ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Создал ASP Net Core приложение с авторизацией, попытался выполнить в консоли NuGet

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

получил сообщение об ошибке

```
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.
```

Думаю, что проблема в том что существует 2 контекста данных. Один от Identity, другой от меня

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Как их совместить?

```
public class MobileContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public MobileContext(DbContextOptions<MobileContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

Вроде нашел решение, не не смог разобраться самостоятельно, что именно необходимо сделать.
[Форум с решение](https://forums.asp.net/t/2097643.aspx?How%20to%20combine%20two%20DbContext)

Comment: на форуме по ссылке предлагают из двух контекстов сделать один. Чтобы выполнить миграцию для ApplicationDbContext  попробуйте так: `PM> Add-Migration InitialApplication -Context ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: а зачем вам 2 контекста? IdentityContext это по сути тот же контекст баз данных, просто с несколькими дополнительными таблицами

Comment: Авторизация пользователей и данные в разных местах.